# Structure of a ring

Tags: ring-theory

Let $(A, +, .)$ be a non associative ring with
$(A, +) \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $x$ and $y$ as an additive group with $p^3x=py=0$. Also $A$ is generated by $x$ as a ring. Define $A^{i+1}=\sum_{j=1}^{i}A^j.A^{i+1-j}$. Given that $A^i=0$ for all $i \geq 3$.. Then find the element which generates $(A^2,+)$ as an additive group.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$ Let $y=ax+bx^2$ where $a,b \in \{1,\cdots,p^3\}$. Note $A^2=\mathbb{Z}(x^2)$. So $(A^2,+)$ is generated by a single element. As $x$ generates $A$, $x \notin A^2$. So $(A^2,+)$ is either generated by $px, p^2x, y$. If $px$ generates $(A^2,+)$, then $|(A^2,+)|=p^2$. Now $px^2=px.x=0$ this implies $|(A^2,+)|=p$, a contradiction.
But after that I am not able to proceed further. The answer is $(A^2,+)$ is generated by $p^2x$. Can anyone please help me to understand why $y$ is not a generator of $(A^2,+)$.

Comment: What is a non associative ring?

Comment: The multiplication is not associative.  That is what I wanted to mean.

Comment: I guessed that but it does not completely answer my question.

Comment: How do you prove $y=ax+bx^2$?

Comment: Given that $x$ is a generator of that ring and $A^3=0$ means that $A=\mathbb{Z}(x)+\mathbb{Z}(x^2)$, so y must be of that form.

Comment: $A^3=0$ but what about $A^2\cdot A^2$?

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the problem regarding $A^2.A^2$ and products like that.